# Generating Numerical Permutations (Iteration vs Recursion)

Tags: python, iteration, permutation, numeric

I think I am trying to do something quite fundamental and quite simple. For this reason, I was sure Stack Overflow would already have a post regarding this task but I guess not? Maybe it is an inconsequential concept? Apologies if a post for this already exists. I couldn't find it.

Here is what I want to accomplish: Given a list length **n** and a maximum element value **m**, generate all of the permutations of the list with each element varying between 0 and **m**.

**QUESTIONS: 1. Is there a way to do this recursively? 2. Is recursion optimal (in terms of computational resources, O time, etc.) for this concept or is iteration better? 3. Is there a better way (less complicated) to achieve this using iteration (see my code below)?**

*more information found below*

**I have edited my code and the two examples to produce and exhibit complete solutions**

Here are two examples:

Example 1: n = 3, m = 2
Output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Example 1: n = 2, m = 4
Output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[0, 4]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 0]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
```

My intuition tells me this can be done recursively but I can't think of how to do it (I'm a beginner programmer). Currently, I have a solution to achieve this iteratively:

```
def permute(curr_permute,max_num,reset_flgs,reset_ind):
    '''
    Increment Logic Structure
    '''
    perm_ind = 0
    max_val_flgs = [0]*len(curr_permute)
    for c_i in range(len(curr_permute)):
        if ((curr_permute[c_i] == max_num) and (c_i < (len(curr_permute)-1))):
            if ((reset_ind == c_i) and (reset_flgs[c_i] == 1)):
                reset_ind += 1
                reset_flgs[c_i] = 0
                max_val_flgs[c_i] = 1
                continue
            else:
                perm_ind += 1
                max_val_flgs[c_i] = 1
        elif (c_i == (len(curr_permute)-1)):
            if (curr_permute[c_i] == max_num):
                perm_ind = c_i
                max_val_flgs[c_i] = 1
            else:
                perm_ind = c_i
        elif (curr_permute[c_i] < max_num):
            perm_ind += 1
    '''
    Reverse the lists
    '''
    max_val_flgs.reverse()
    curr_permute.reverse()
    reset_flgs.reverse()
    '''
    Reset Logic Structure
    '''
    for n_i in range(len(curr_permute)):
        if (max_val_flgs[n_i] == 0):
            break
        elif ((max_val_flgs[n_i] == 1) and (reset_flgs[n_i] == 1)):
            curr_permute[n_i] = 0
            perm_ind += -1
    '''
    Reverse the lists
    '''
    curr_permute.reverse()
    reset_flgs.reverse()
    '''
    Apply the permutation increment
    '''
    curr_permute[perm_ind] += 1
    return(curr_permute,reset_flgs,reset_ind)

def Permutation_Generation():
    n = 2
    m = 4
   
    curr_permute = [0]*n
    reset_flgs = [1]*n
    reset_ind = 0
    All_Permutations = [list(curr_permute)]
    while (sum(curr_permute) < (n*m)):
        print(curr_permute)
        [curr_permute,reset_flgs,reset_ind] = permute(curr_permute,m,reset_flgs,reset_ind)
        All_Permutations.append(list(curr_permute))
    print(curr_permute)
    return(All_Permutations)
```

Apologies for the garbage code. Once I came up with a way to do it successfully, I didn't make much effort to clean it up or make it more efficient. My guess is this code is too complicated for the concept I am attempting to address.

Comment: I think most officiant for this is itertools combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your output with n and m are 3, 2, respectively, really make sense. After 6th row `[0, 2, 0]`, shouldn't it be followed by `[0, 2, 1]` instead of `[1, 0, 0]`? Same also happened after 13th row.

Anyway here is an recursive alterantive:

```
n = 3
m = 2

def permutation(n, m):
    if n <= 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(m+1):
            for j in permutation(n-1, m):
                yield [i] + j

# or even shorter
def permutation(n, m):
    return [[i] + j for i in range(m + 1) for j in permutation(n - 1, m)] if n > 0 else []


for i in permutation(n, m):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], ..., [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, my solution fails to generate all the permutations for **n** and **m**. I didn't catch that. I am glad, at least, my examples demonstrated that issue.

Thank you for also providing a recursive solution! It seems far more elegant than my iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

**3.** You want to get all permutations. The number of permutations given n and m is (m+1)^n.
Because you actually want to print all of them the time complexity is also O((m+1)^n), which is what you get when doing it iteratively.

**1+2.** I don't think you should use recursion to do it, O((m+1)^n) is the optimal time you can do it and it's what you get when using iterations. recursion will also take more memory for it's memory stack.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you!

Comment: @J_Aero_Paul Please accept the answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: The post is so new, it won't let me accept the answer. Hahahhaha

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be answered, but I want to contribute an alternative for  the permutation by iteration that is a bit simpler. Here I use list comprehensions, formatted string literals (the f'string' strings) and the eval built-in method. Hope this perspective is helpful to you (somehow?).

```
def get_permutations_list(array_size, max_value):
    '''Returns a list of arrays that represent all permutations between zero
    and max_value'''

    array_member =''
    for_loops=''

    #Does a loop iteration for each member of the permutation list template
    for i in range(array_size):

        #adds a new member in each permutation
        array_member += f'x{i}, '

        #adds a new corresponding for loop
        for_loops+=" for x{i} in range({value})".format(i=i, 
                                                   value=max_value)

    output = f'[[{array_member}] {for_loops}]' #combines it all together
    return eval(output)

a = get_permutations_list(array_size=2, max_value=2)
print(a)
#Result: [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting your code to run. I don't have experience with "formatted string literals". My error shows up at:
'output = f'[[{array_mockup}] {for_loop}]' #combines it all together'. But if I am reading your code correctly, is a nested for loop created for each array/list element? This concerns me because I would want the solution to handle arbitrarily large values of **n**. I think python has a block stack limit of 20? Is that a limitation in your code or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Hi! About that error: I made some changes to the variable names and forgot to update some of them. It should be fixed now. F strings is the name of the formatted literal strings - just google and you will see it is a simple way of formatting strings in python. And you are correct about the my code and block stack limitation. I did not cover all requisites - my bad!

Comment: I got your code to work! Thanks for the update. Also it appears your code does in fact work for n>20. I don't know whether this is because python increased the blockstack limit or whether your code doesn't actually nest the for loops. Curious. In any case, at least your code yields a complete solution. Apparently my solution is missing certain permutations because I haven't tackled all the different cases with my nested if statement structure. I am trying to solve it just as a practice exercise. Thanks again for your contribution!